# cufon fonts do not work on all my pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks, cufon

I have a problem with my page: on start page `cufon-yui` is loaded fine, but when I go to another page, it doesn't load. But when I refresh, it looks fine. I use turbolinks.

[image: application.html.erb]

[image: application.js]

Comment: I used jquery turbolink gem but it`s not work

Comment: I used jquery turbolink gem but it`s not works. In cufon-yui.js i try to put  var ready;
ready = function() {
  cufon-yui.js all code
};
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turbolinks works by replacing the page content instead of navigating to a new page. If you're calling cufon-yui on `document.ready`, then it will NOT be called when you navigate to a new page. Your code should then look like:

```
$(document).on 'ready page:load', function(event)
{
  Cufon.replace("whatever you're replacing");
  // And whatever other Cufon code you're using is.
}
```

This way, it'll be called both when the document is ready, as well as when `page:load` is called by Turbolinks upon the completion of the page loading process.